# Getting "No tests were found error" when executing Test class in Junit5

Tags: intellij-idea, junit5

Following is the pom.xml file I am using in my Intellij Idea maven project :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>code</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${maven.compiler.source}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
                <version>5.7.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Everything compiles fine. But when I run the Test file containing @Test annotations. 
I get `No tests were found error`

Here is the test class :

```
package com.lab1;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class PascalTriangleTests {
    @Test
    private void test(){
        PascalTriangle pascalTriangle = new PascalTriangle();
        pascalTriangle.generate(1);
        assertEquals(pascalTriangle.getPascalTriangle().size(),1,"It should be one");
    }
}
```

This is the class that if run it for some reason doesn't run the test function

Comment: Can you add your test class with imports here?

Comment: Added the test class

Comment: Do you need to add `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` annotation in your test class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `private` modifier - it is not allowed in tests methods.

Comment: Remoing the private worked. Thanks!. One more thing. Is the way I am using Junit5 is same as something called JUnit test runner? I see that Junit test runner comes up for Junit4.